# multiple outputs in do while loop with nested if/else structure

Tags: java, do-while

A little confused here. if i un-comment the System.out.println statement i get the error "else without if" do i need to reorganize my code or is there an easy fix here.  Using freeTTS API.

```
     do//begin do loop
    {

    if //if else structure within post test loop
            (guess == computerNumber)
            //System.out.println("Congratulations you guessed correctly!");
            voice.speak("congrats you are correct");
    else if
            (guess < computerNumber)
            //System.out.println("Sorry, your guess was to low. Try Again.");
            voice.speak("sorry, too low");
    else if
            (guess > computerNumber)
            //5System.out.println("Sorry, your guess was to high. Try Again.");
            voice.speak("too high ,bro-ski! go lower!!");
            guess = keyboard.nextInt();
    } 
    while (guess !=computerNumber);//end post test loop
    voice.speak("nice. you finally guessed the correct answer. But, you should always start with 42 since that is the answer to the life the universe and everything");
```

Comment: Úse curly brackets, `{` resp `}`, or else you are bound to run in loads of troubles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per jls, in 14.9.7

If the value is true, then the first contained Statement (the one before the else
keyword) is executed; the if-then-else statement completes normally if and
only if execution of that statement completes normally.

value is expression in if.

A block is a sequence of statements, local class declarations, and local variable
declaration statements within braces.

```
Block: { BlockStatementsopt }
```

so you've to give those 2 lines within braces. if not only first line is considered. The next line is passed, when compiler sees the else part it needs an if but we don't have one associated with it so it reports an error.

Answer (score 0):

use `{} bracket` for multiple statement in `if-else`

```
if(guess == computerNumber){
    System.out.println("Congratulations you guessed correctly!");
    voice.speak("congrats you are correct");
 }else if (guess < computerNumber) {
    System.out.println("Sorry, your guess was to low. Try Again.");
    voice.speak("sorry, too low");
} else if (guess > computerNumber) {
    System.out.println("Sorry, your guess was to high. Try Again.");
    voice.speak("too high ,bro-ski! go lower!!");
    guess = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Put the If blocks  and else Blocks in `{}`